# Azure Table Storage Query in .NET With Property Names Unknown at Design Time

Tags: linq, azure, azure-table-storage

Is there a TSQL equivalent for Azure Table Storage? 
I want to add hock type queries in .NET when the property names are not known at design time.

From my understating of LINQ, you need to reference existing public properties.

```
 var selectedOrders = from o in context.Orders
                 where o.Freight > 30
                 orderby o.ShippedDate descending 
                 select o;
```

Freight and ShippedDate must be public properties defined at design time.  I don't have structured properties (or even structured classes).

What if I don't know the property names at design time?  You can add new property names to a Table in a very add hock manner but how can you consume them?

Via the REST API can define a dynamic query

```
    Request Syntax:
    GET /myaccount/Customers()?$filter=(Rating%20ge%203)%20and%20(Rating%20le%206)$select=PartitionKey,RowKey,Address,CustomerSince  HTTP/1.1
```

Are there tools to use REST in .NET (in a dynamic manner)?

From REST API documentation: 
Use the logical operators defined by the .NET Client Library for ADO.NET Data Services Framework to compare a property to a value. Note that it is not possible to compare a property to a dynamic value; one side of the expression must be a constant.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894031.aspx

If the answer is you need to use SQL if you need TSQL type queries then OK.

What I think I am learning is that Table Storage is designed to serialize classes (especially if you have many many instances to serialize).  From this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179423.aspx
The schema for a table is defined as a C# class.  This is the model used by ADO.NET Data Services.  The schema is known only to the client application and simplifies data access.  The server does not enforce this schema.

```
    [DataServiceKey("PartitionKey", "RowKey")]
    public class Blog
    {
        // ChannelName 
        public string PartitionKey { get; set; } 
        // PostedDate 
        public string RowKey { get; set; } 

        // User defined properties
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
        public string RatingAsString { get; }
        protected string Id { get; set; }
    }
```

A user will upload a file that will go to BLOB and string fields to describe the file.  It needs to be able to scale to millions of records.  Would only search on two required fields (properties): custID and batch.  Don't need to search for other fields but I do need to preserve them and allow the user just to add new fields in a batch.   Need it to scale to millions of records and hence BLOB storage is appropriate for the files.  What I think I get out of Table Storage is the ability to use REST at the client to download files and fields. Need to optimized for up to 100,000 downloads at a time and supports restart.  Upload is going to be relatively small batches, and that will probably not be REST as I need to do some upload validation on the server side.

What I am thinking about doing is two tables.  Where the second is designed for dynamic data.

```
    Master
      PartitionKey CustID 
      RowKey       GUID
      string       batch
      string       filename
    Fields
      PartitionKey CustID+Guid
      RowKey       fieldName
      string       value
```

The fieldName is required to be unique. 
The queries on Master would be by CustID or by CustID and batch. 
The queries on Fields would be by PartitionKey.
Comments, please.

Comment: I don't think it would be hard to write one. I have thought myself that I'd prefer table storage to work with dynamic data than concrete classes.

Comment: Would you use REST and parse the Response?  I am surprised there is not a .NET library for dynamic queries to Table Storage.  Am I looking at Table Storage incorrectly?   Is the sole intent of Table Storage to serialize large (or small) numbers of concrete classes?   When I look at REST and LINQ I get two different views.

Comment: The table storage API (i.e. the linq you're writing) is just an abstraction over the top of the REST interface. You could write your own as you correctly point out. It is surprising that a more dynamic interface doesn't exist in C#, but it's not really a dynamic language, most people like working with static types. You could always switch to node.js or ruby (for example) where dynamic libraries are available. Table storage is designed to store a large number of small object of an unfixed schema.

Comment: @RichardAstbury Thanks,  I like working with static types I just don't have them here.   What I am thinking about doing is creating a static class to store the dynamic data.  Please look at the new last paragraph and commment.

Comment: If you're looking for the best performance, your variable fields fit within the restrictions of properties of a table and don't mind writing a bunch of code, for what you want to do, skip LINQ and just use the rest API.  Based on comments here, put it in a library and share it, it could be popular.

Comment: Table Storage does need a library for dynamic use but I don't need it bad enough to write a library based on creating HTTP Request and then parsing out the Response right now.

Comment: I am going to put out a product to do this.  Basically it will be a query builder to Table Storage with also a link to BLOB if that row has a file file associated with it. Check back, the basic version will be free with source code.

Comment: @BalamBalam I wrote a library for that, check out Cyan in nuget or cyannet.codeplex.org, looking for feedback and contributors;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also created a library for using dynamic types with table storage:

To use it, first, create a context object:

```
var context = new DynamicTableContext("TableName", credentials);
```

Then inserting a record is easy:

```
context.Insert(new { PartitionKey="1", RowKey="1", Value1="Hello", Value2="World" });
```

You can do the same with a dictionary:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dictionary["PartitionKey"] = "2";
dictionary["RowKey"] = "2";
dictionary["Value3"] = "FooBar";
context.Insert(dictionary);
```

Retrieving an entity is straight forward, just pass in values for partition key and row key:

```
dynamic entity = content.Get("1", "1");
```

You can also pass in a query:

```
foreach (dynamic item in context.Query("Value1 eq 'Hello'"))
{
  Console.WriteLine(item.RowKey);
}
```

It's available on github here: https://github.com/richorama/AzureSugar

Comment: Could you help me out on the license.  What I think I read is that I can use this in compliled form (with no warranty) in a commercial product.  In compiled form I do not need to distribute the text of the license.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a question of Table Storage, it is of LINQ. You can write dynamic LINQ (unfortunately losing why LINQ is so awesome) using Expression trees. LINQ is really just Expression Trees in the background anyway.

So three responses to your question:

1. Here is how to write [dynamic LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/bb737920.aspx)
2. Here is information on a [dynamic LINQ library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) to make things less ugly
3. And finally you can't use order by on Table Storage queries :)

Comment: Thanks but I am still confused.  On the second link there is syntax.  "where p.Category.CategoryName = ...".  That left hand side does not allow variables.  If I don't know the property names at design time how can I use LINQ?  If the answer is you can't with LINQ then I will move on (hence my question on if REST will do it).  LINQ is awesome if structure is know at design time.  For this project I have to deal with a large amount of structured data but I don't know the structure of that data at design time.  I just pass that structure on.

Comment: Continue reading the article - it introduces the query like "where p.Category.CategoryName = ..." and then continues to explain that you can also achieve this with the Dynamic LINQ Library like .Where("CategoryID=2 and UnitPrice>3"). Using strings allows you to make it dynamic. Similar to REST of course but it will be more consistent if you are using LINQ elsewhere. Regardless this is how you introduce dynamism into your LINQ work if that is what you require

Comment: OK can build the where dynamically.  How do you get the result back.  What is the syntax to read a property value when the property name is not known at design time?  What is the syntax for even creating the LINQ query object without providing a schema.  Refer to the documentation referenced above: "schema is defined as a class".  I don't have the properties for that defining class at design time.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself I just found it and thought it might help you when making your Dynamic LINQ simpler to write. Have you tried looking at the documentation for the library?

Comment: There are several references to the documentation in my question and in my comments to you.  I am not going to down vote you but you are only supposed to post as an answer something you tested or done before yourself.

Comment: Comments like that really discourage me from trying to help on stackoverflow. Your suggestion is that I am lazy for not writing and testing a solution for you. I have written dynamic linq before and it works well but I was also pointing you and others in an alternative helpful direction. If you would prefer not to use the library and write your own dynamic linq or even write your own custom code then cool.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a dynamic client for the REST API
It's called [Cyan](http://cyannet.codeplex.com/), you can find it on Codeplex or in nuget searching for "Cyan".

Your query would be:

```
var cyan = new CyanTableClient("account", "password")
var items = cyan.Query("Customers",
    filter: "(Rating ge 3) and (Rating le 6)",
    fields: new[] { "PartitionKey", "RowKey", "Address", "CustomerSince" });
```

You can then access fields in this way:

```
var item = items.First();

// the address
string address = item.Address;

// or you can cast to CyanEntity and access fields from a Dictionary
var entity = (CyanEntity)item;
string address2 = (string)entity.Fields["Address"];
```

It's still a work in progress, please send me your feedback and feel free to contribute!

Answer (score 1):

I have written a Azure table storage client which supports both static and late binding (via a dictionary). Any table property not contained in the entity type will be captured in a dictionary. It also supports arrays, enums, large data, serialization and more. More features are in the works too!

You can get it at http://www.lucifure.com .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and approached it initially by having a table like your "Fields" table - lots of very small records with key/value. I came across two issues - one is that [Nagle's algorithm messes with your inserts](http://robertgreiner.com/2012/06/why-is-azure-table-storage-so-slow/) if you're not doing it asynchronously (up to 500ms per insert) and the other is that [Azure's scalability targets](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/11/02/windows-azure-s-flat-network-storage-and-2012-scalability-targets.aspx) limit you to 20,000 entities/sec across a storage account.

In the end I solved it by storing a `Dictionary<string, string>` using custom read/write methods and I've written that up in [How can I store arbitrary key value pairs in Azure table storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595486/how-can-i-store-arbitrary-key-value-pairs-in-azure-table-storage/14595487)

Answer (score 0):

Azure table service does not support order by query, it only supports `where`, `select`, `first`, `firstorsdefault`, `from` and `take`. You'll have write to two separate queries.