# How can I store arbitrary key value pairs in Azure table storage?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-table-storage

**Background**

I am receiving CSV data files from clients that contain a large amount of data that I don't need and a small amount of data that I do. In the future I may need to access that data and although I'm archiving the original data files I was hoping for something a bit easier to query. I was hoping for a solution that didn't mean the data files stayed in the same format - i.e. the client may add/remove columns and I don't want my implementation to bail on missing data or fail to archive additional data.

As I'm building the application in Azure, Azure table storage looked correct to me - I could read the data files and then store whatever key/value pairs I read into the data store.

**Upshot**

I would like to know how to store a `Dictionary<K, V>` or `Hashtable` or some other key/value pairs in Azure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By overriding the ReadEntity and WriteEntity methods on classes derived from TableEntity, additional properties can be stored.

Here's my naive implementation

```
public class TestEntity : TableEntity {

    public TestEntity(string a, string b) {
        PartitionKey = a;
        RowKey = b;
        DataItems = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> DataItems { get; set; }

    public override IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> WriteEntity(OperationContext operationContext) {
        var results = base.WriteEntity(operationContext);
        foreach (var item in DataItems) {
            results.Add("D_" + item.Key, new EntityProperty(item.Value));
        }
        return results;
    }

    public override void ReadEntity(IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> properties, OperationContext operationContext) {
        base.ReadEntity(properties, operationContext);

        DataItems = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (var item in properties) {
            if (item.Key.StartsWith("D_")) {
                string realKey = item.Key.Substring(2);
                ItemData[realKey] = item.Value.StringValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've noted that Azure table storage can only store a total of 255 key/value pairs – or 252 custom ones once PartitionKey, etc. is taken into account, so this has to be handled somewhere as well.

Comment: I've [blogged about this](http://uber-rob.co.uk/2013/01/storing-arbitrary-keyvalue-pairs-like-hastable-or-dictionary-in-azure-table-storage/) and would welcome any additional information anyone has, or just a note if you're using it!

Comment: How about if you just serialize your Dictionary<string, string>() using binaryformatter (or XML formatter) a write the entire object to a single entity property of type byte[] (or string)? I would use that approach instead.

Comment: Leaving them as additional properties would (in theory, not tested) allow me to use [TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionFor*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj682517.aspx) to query on that data (which could be useful if I suddenly needed to use it rather than just archive it). Serialized, I imagine that would be quite tricky.

And while you do sidestep the 252 property limit, you still have to worry about bumping into the 64kb-per-property limit (so you'd have to serialize over several properties).

Comment: If I had a very large number of known-to-be-small key/value pairs I may have ended up using that solution though, my data probably leans me towards mine (for now).

Comment: true for byte[] limitation, but still quering on anything other than PL&RK will be slow. Have you looked at Lokad.Cloud's Fat Entities - https://github.com/Lokad/lokad-cloud/wiki/FatEntities