# Storing POCO in Azure table with private setter

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

When storing C# objects in Azure storage table, properties with private setters are ignored. Is it possible to write these properties to the table without making the setter public?

Json.net provides this feature through JsonProperty attribute. Are there any such attributes available for storage table? The only property I could find is IgnorePropertyAttribute which is used to ignore a property.

```
class TestEntity : TableEntity
{
    public TestEntity(string property1, string property2)
    {
        this.Property1 = property1;
        this.Property2 = property2;
    }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; private set; }
}

TestEntity testEntity = new TestEntity("Value1", "Value2");
testEntity.PartitionKey = "PartitionKey";
testEntity.RowKey = "RowKey";
TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(testEntity);
table.Execute(insertOperation);
```

In the above example, only Property1 (Value1) is stored in the table. The value for Property2 is not stored. The only way to store this to change the setter to public.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could show us some of the code involved - [mcve].

Comment: I have added a sample code that demonstrates this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I store arbitrary key value pairs in Azure table storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595486/how-can-i-store-arbitrary-key-value-pairs-in-azure-table-storage) Please refer to answer there to add your Property2 into WriteEntity() and ReadEntity() methods.

Comment: I was looking for a solution where I don't have to convert the object to dictionary but I could use this as a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to override the `ITableEntity` interface, since version 8.0 Table Storage SDK supports writing and reading custom .Net objects to Table Storage (including the properties with private setters). There are even multiple ways supported by the SDK.

Your custom objects do not even need to implement ITableEntity interface, or inherit from TableEntity class. They can also contain complex nested properties. All of these are supported except the `IEnumerable` type indexed properties (Lists, Arrays, etc.).

So here is how:

1. You can use the helper methods `TableEntity.Flatten` static method to convert your custom .Net entity into a flat Dictionary of EntityProperties. Create a DynamicTableEntity with that Dictionary and write to table storage. You can read that entity back using the same PK, RK and use `TableEntity.ConvertBack<YourEntityType>` method to recompose your original entity.
2. Second alternative approach is, you can use `TableEntityAdapter`  class in the SDK.
   You can look at the sample usage answer I gave in a similar question here:
   [Sample writing a generic object to Azure Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47044207/sample-writing-a-generic-object-to-azure-storage)

Comment: I am using TableEntityAdapter to store my object in the table. However, the properties with private setters are not stored in the table.

Comment: do you also have a getter (even private) for these properties or are they read only.? I recommend you to post a new question with the code and I can have a  look.